# cargo-clone and cargo-edit don’t build on my Windows 10 PC

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I installed Visual Studio C++ and Rust. Most things work fine, but building cargo-edit and cargo-clone fail. The error code hints at cmake missing but it's one of the items built ok. Windows 10 specific issue.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to help from the IRC #rust-beginners channel I found out that I needed to install cmake from cmake.org. Make sure you have it add itself to the path and restart your command prompt.

[Cmake download](https://cmake.org/download/)